# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2 + 2s+ 2}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2 + 2s+ 2}$

$s^2 + 2s + 2 = (s+1)^2 + 1$

$F(s) = \frac{1}{(s+1)^2 + 1} $

$f(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \frac {1}{(s + 1)^2 + 1} = e^{-t} \sin t $

$f(t- \pi) = e^{-(t-\pi)} \sin (t- \pi) $

so answer is $ e^{\pi - t} \sin (t-\pi) U (t- \pi) $

Why am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that the Laplace transform of $\sin\omega_0 t$ and $\sin\omega_0 t u(t)$ is different. The Laplace transform of $\sin \omega_0 t$ is $${\pi\over i}(\delta(\omega-\omega_0)-\delta(\omega+\omega_0))$$which means that the region of convergence of this Laplace transform is the imaginary-line and the Laplace transfom of $\sin \omega_0 t u(t)$ is $$\dfrac{\omega_0}{s^2+\omega_0^2}$$both can be derived using the definition

Comment: I don't think the OP is doing two-sided Laplace transforms anywhere.

Comment: He is wrong in line 4 because $L^{-1}\dfrac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}=e^{-t}\sin t u(t)$

Comment: When everything is one-sided anyway, we omit $u(t)$ as a factor because it is identically equal to $1$ on the domain of interest.

Comment: That's right and i agree with it. This is an alternative approach but i think when saying Laplace transform or  inverse Laplace transform we refer to 2-sided definition.

Comment: Conventionally in classes like undergraduate differential equations, at least in the US, the Laplace transform is kept one-sided at all times. When two-sided calculation is needed, we change variables a little bit and call it a Fourier transform. Someone well acquainted with analysis can easily change gears between the two at will, but someone only acquainted with it at the level of simple calculations will tend to be confused by this distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually correct. If you're comparing it to the result from software, for example Wolfram Alpha gives $-e^{\pi-t} \theta(t-\pi) \sin(t)$, then you just need to use some algebra/trig identities to convert between the results. In this case it is to convert from $\sin(t-\pi)$ to $-\sin(t)$.